# Facebook Marketing API: Requested URL returns Object w/ ID does not exist, but works in browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This one is a little odd. I am making a request that has been made many times before, but for some reason is being denied. However, it is only being denied from postman/arc and from my server. If I paste it in the browser, I get the list of campaigns just like I would expect.

So this works in the browser:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/act_blahblahblah/campaigns?fields=name,status,objective&access_token=mytoken

But if I try to make a request from cURL or test it in postman or arc I get this error:

> Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'act_blahblahblah' does not
>   exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not
>   support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

(Of course, I have replaced the real ad account w/ blahblahblah for this example).

The token is valid AND I made sure that the account ID is listed in advanced settings. This has worked in the past, so I'm not sure why I am getting it now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It actually was a token issue, but just not one I could tell right off the bat. I am using an extended token that works, but needed to be refreshed after a change was made. So I got a fresh token, extended that, and tried it with the new extended token and it works just fine now. Just remember kids, if in doubt, get a fresh token. You too self. You too.

Answer (score 0):

The graph API explorer is helpful in testing access token issues.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Also, most access tokens expire quickly, and if you need a permanent token for a prod environment, i would recommend looking at system user tokens.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser/